# Python aiohttp: cancel async execution on met condition

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-asyncio, aiohttp

I have written an async brute-force script for a CTF game that looks like this

```
async def bound_fetch(sem, session, answer):
    #  generating url, headers and json ...
    async with sem, session.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            print('Right answer found: %s' % json['answer'])


async def run(words):
    tasks = []
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(3)
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        for word in words:
            task = asyncio.create_task(bound_fetch(sem=sem, session=session, answer=''.join(word)))
            tasks.append(task)
        print("Generated %d possible answers. Checking %s" % (len(tasks), base_url))
        await asyncio.gather(*tasks)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
    future = asyncio.ensure_future(run(possible_answers))
    loop.run_until_complete(future)
```

my reference was this tutorial: https://pawelmhm.github.io/asyncio/python/aiohttp/2016/04/22/asyncio-aiohttp.html

I was wondering if this is the right way to do it in aiohttp or if I made things too complicated (because I don't need to process all the responses, just to know which one has a status 200)? How do I cancel the processing when the condition (status code) is met?

Comment: Ok, I managed to cancel the execution by `raise StopIteration` when the condition is met and instead of `await asyncio.gather(*tasks)` I do `await asyncio.wait(tasks, return_when=asyncio.FIRST_EXCEPTION)`. If somebody knows a more elegant way, please post an answer :)

Comment: You might want to raise something other than `StopIteration` - since `StopIteration` is used by Python, it's not a good idea to use it as a business exception. I've posted an answer showing how to synchronize using an `Event`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I was wondering if this is the right way to do it in aiohttp

Your code is reasonably idiomatic. At top-level you can omit `asyncio.ensure_future` and simply call `asyncio.run(run(possible_answers))`.

> How do I cancel the processing when the condition (status code) is met?

You can use an event or future object and wait on that instead of using `gather`. As you are probably aware, `gather` isn't needed to *run* the coroutines (they run as soon as scheduled with `create_task`), its explicit purpose is to wait until all the coroutines complete. The `Event`-based synchronization could look like this:

```
async def bound_fetch(sem, session, answer, done):
    #  generating url, headers and json ...
    async with sem, session.post(url=url, json=json, headers=headers) as response:
        if response.status == 200:
            done.set()
            done.run_answer = json['answer']

async def run(words):
    sem = asyncio.Semaphore(3)
    done = asyncio.Event()
    async with aiohttp.ClientSession() as session:
        tasks = []
        for word in words:
            tasks.append(asyncio.create_task(bound_fetch(
                sem=sem, session=session, answer=''.join(word), done=done)))
        print("Generated %d possible answers. Checking %s" % (len(words), base_url))
        await done.wait()
        print('Right answer found: %s' % done.run_answer)
        for t in tasks:
            t.cancel()
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply. This looks much cleaner indeed. My code editor complains that there is no await before the asyncio.create_task(), but I assume this is on purpose so it is not synchronous? By the way, I am not sure though if the Semaphore works - I get quite a lot of connections here. Can I log the number of active connections at a time somehow?

Comment: Hmm, it looks like this way the program terminates with "RuntimeError: Session is closed Task exception was never retrieved". Is it supposed to be this way?

Comment: @Phil I think your IDE is being a bit overzealous. Still, because of your second remark I amended the code to cancel the tasks once the answer is found. This should resolve both issues as the return value of `create_task` is now used and the tasks are canceled prior to exiting the main coroutine. (I suspect `asyncio.run` was trying to "finish up" the event loop which caused the leftover tasks to try to do something with the session that has by now been closed.) Please check if that solves the issue.

Comment: Yes, it works without errors now. Can you please confirm that the semaphore is used correctly here? I copied that from Pawel's website and I know Dijkstra's theory behind semaphores, but I am not sure if I am using it correctly. Here for example: https://tutorialedge.net/python/concurrency/python-asyncio-semaphores-tutorial/ the auther uses acquire() and release() by individual workers on the semaphore and that is missing in my code

Comment: @Phil Your use of semaphores is fine because the `async with semaphore` automatically does `await semaphore.acquire()` on entry into the `with` block and `semaphore.release()` on exit. This is more reliable than calling `acquire` and `release` manually because it will correctly release the semaphore in case of an exception or other premature exit from the function.